# Determine if a number contains a specific digit

Tags: java, digits

My idea is to create a loop and not print numbers that contain a 3 in them like 13, 23, 43,etc. between 2 numbers given by a user.

My problem is on the loop. How do I check that the numbers contain a 3 on them?

For example if it prints from 2 to 24. It should not print 3,13 and 23.

```
        for(int i = x; i <= y; i++){

           if(i%3 == 0){
               System.out.print("");      

           else{
               System.out.println(i);
           }
           
       }
```

Comment: You don't want mod (`%`) 3, you want to  check if any of the digits of the base 10 representation are 3 (I assume).

Comment: I think you mean `i%10 == 3` ?

Comment: yes it was i%10 == 3, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    for(int i = x; i <= y; i++){

        if(i%10 == 3){
            System.out.print("");  
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        
    }
```